# How to increase precision of y axis in matplotlib to plot close curves farther apart

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, deep-learning

I am plotting the training and validation losses of two different CNN architectures on the same task. The losses differ at the third decimal place. When I am plotting the losses using matplotlib.pyplot, the curves are too close to see the difference between them.

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('/content/final arch1 loss.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('/content/final arch2 loss.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
f = lambda x,pos: str(x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.001))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(f))

data1_loss = data1.loss
data1_val_loss = data1.val_loss

data2_loss = data2.loss
data2_val_loss = data2.val_loss

plt.plot(data1_loss, label='arch1 train loss')
plt.plot(data1_val_loss, label='arch1 val loss')
plt.plot(data2_loss, label='arch2 train loss')
plt.plot(data2_val_loss, label='arch2 val loss')
plt.legend()
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('graph.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

I followed other answers on SO to increase number of ticks on y-axis, but that doesn't seem to pull apart the graphs at all. How can I increase the precision to separate out the graphs of the two architectures?

---

Edit -
As suggested by Trenton McKinney and Jody Klymak in the comments, using log scale (using ax.set_yscale('log') and ax.plot()) helped pull the graphs farther -
[image]

Comment: This is a data processing question.  You can subtract a baseline case or divide by a baseline case.   You can display in log space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I can try plotting the difference. But is there no method to do this in matplotlib or any other library as they are meant for scientific computing, and scale of the order of e-3 must be available..

Comment: You should probably use `ax.plot(...)`, not `plt.plot(...)` and try `ax.set_yscale('log')`

Comment: Matplotlib is used extensively for scientific computing.  It’s not clear what you expect to happen here.  You may want to try ax.set_ylim()?